# Pandas and Openpyxl overwrites excel

Tags: excel, pandas

I am using pandas to convert csv file to excel and the excelwriter to draw some charts and save the file.

Now i want to make some formatting like changing color of cells which i am unable to do so with pandas and xlsxwriter. Therefore, i used openpyxl.

I loaded my worksheet where charts and other data is stored and make some formatting changes in the worksheet and save the file. Openpyxl removes the charts from the sheet.

anyone faced this issue ?

Comment: Which version of the **openpyxl** are you using?

Comment: openpyxl 2.4.8
and I am using python 3.6 and 3.4 local and production respectively

Comment: This problem seems to be -mostly- resolved by version: 2.5-a3. Please see: https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/847/existing-charts-in-excel-document-get

Comment: Thank you for your input. 
Problem is its hard to update the version at production due to some permission issues/dependencies.